# Unity framework files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unity-container

Can enybody share .dll files from Unity framework for .net framework 4.
I don't want download .msi from oficial site because it requests VS2008 installed.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17866) is just the binaries and has no VS2008 requirement.

Comment: Thank you. Yesterday it was not available.

Answer (score 0):

You should get used to NuGet,

http://nuget.org/packages/Unity